# MapBox Background Image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, mapbox

Good morning everyone, 
I have a quick question about some background images in MapBox. For those who don't know MapBox, it is a online provider of custom maps that quickly create beautiful interactive maps and data visualizations. I created a map project, and wanted to put that map as a background image. I am given an embed option and here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head></head> 
<body>
    <iframe width='100%' height='800px' frameBorder='0' src='https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/ericpark.k8ehofdl/attribution,zoompan,zoomwheel,geocoder,share.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpY3BhcmsiLCJhIjoiS3pKZ0duVSJ9.tLg7r9w5zppYheaOYcv_DA'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I want the Mapbox html to take the entire background.I have tried placing the url provided into a background-image: url() in css, but it does not function.

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/ericpark.k8ehofdl/attribution,zoompan,zoomwheel,geocoder,share.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpY3BhcmsiLCJhIjoiS3pKZ0duVSJ9.tLg7r9w5zppYheaOYcv_DA");
}
```

Does anyone know how I might do this?

Thanks, 
Eric

Comment: The only way you could make this a true background image is by taking a screenshot of the map and saving it as an image somewhere, then use that image. This is only a valid solution if you don't care about keeping the interactive functionality

Comment: Hey Jonathan, Thanks for the response. I was hoping to keep the interactivity of MapBox, would this be possible at all? Whether it be through HTML/CSS or utilizing Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon here from Stack - I actually do most of the geo stuff here.

If you want to do this the proper way, you're going to have to embed it in a div and put the content that you want over it in its own container div. You can see a pretty straightforward implementation of what you want in the [API docs on Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/). You can adjust the settings of the map using the JavaScript API (hiding the controls, setting the center, etc.).

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpY3BhcmsiLCJhIjoiS3pKZ0duVSJ9.tLg7r9w5zppYheaOYcv_DA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map-container', 'ericpark.k8ehofdl');
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map-background,
#map-container,
#map-overlay,
#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#map-background {
  z-index: -1;
}
#map-container {
  z-index: 0;
}
#map-overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  background: none;
}
#content {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-background">
    <div id="map-container">
    </div>
    <div id="map-overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- This is where your regular content should be -->
    <p style="color: #fff; text-align: center; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 2.0em;">This is where your foreground code should be.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Good luck Eric :)

---

## EDIT: Restoring interactivity

I've changed the code to get rid of the overlay and some of the blocking styles. Try that.

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpY3BhcmsiLCJhIjoiS3pKZ0duVSJ9.tLg7r9w5zppYheaOYcv_DA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map-container', 'ericpark.k8ehofdl');
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-container">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- This is where your regular content should be -->
    <p style="color: #fff; text-align: center; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 2.0em;">This is where your foreground code should be.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, and if you want to keep the interactivity of the map, you just need to remove the `#map-overlay` div that is currently covering the map in the above code snippet.

Comment: Hey Jon,  Thanks for the help! I got the code running, but can't seem to get the map interactivity. I removed both the div and styling, but still can't seem to get the map to zoom in or out. I will post my Github site once it updates.

Answer (score 0):

To mimic a "background-image" effect with mapbox you could do something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    #map_bg {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:800px;
    }
    #map_bg iframe {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

    .content {
        z-index:1;
        position:relative;
    }

</head> 
<body>
    <div id="map_bg">
        <iframe class="mapbox" frameBorder='0' src='https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/ericpark.k8ehofdl/attribution,zoompan,zoomwheel,geocoder,share.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZXJpY3BhcmsiLCJhIjoiS3pKZ0duVSJ9.tLg7r9w5zppYheaOYcv_DA'></iframe>
         <div class="content">
             This is other content on the page.
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You position the map absolutely relative to it's parent which allows content to overlap it (much like a background image). By adding a `z-index:1` to the other content you can ensure it appears on top of the map;

Answer (score 0):

I dont think just putting link as background image will work. Mapbox might be rendering map in canvas.

I just found [this](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/). Try this. I am not much familiar with mapbox